# Java try-throw-catch troubles

Tags: java

I want to execute a bunch of commands which throw exceptions but I'm having problems with the program executing properly.

This is the basic outline of my code:

```
try
{
   command1 //all three throw exceptions
   command2
   command3
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   //log the exception in a txt file and continue onto the next command
}
```

If command1 throws an exception, how do I get my program to move onto command2? In other words, how do I get back to the try-block and continue executing from where it left off? Thanks.

Comment: Are the commands dependent on the success of the ones before them? You could break them all out into separate `try`-`catch` blocks if they can run independently of one another.

Comment: Yes, and even better, put calling and error handling in to one function. e.g. `executeAllCommands` calls `executeCommand1` and `executeCommand2` which each `try { commandN() } catch ... {}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can never get back into the try block once you're in the catch block. You'd have to make three blocks to continue executing.

```
try { command1(); }
catch (Exception e) { log(e);  }
try { command2(); }
catch (Exception e) { log(e);  }
try { command3(); }
catch (Exception e) { log(e);  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that this is homework, you likely ought to know about the `finally` block as well.

Consecutive try/catch is fine and all, unless you really need command2 to happen no matter what - even if the handling for an exception from command1 fails.

```
try {
    command1();
} catch (Exception e) {
    command1Failed(e);
} finally {
    try {
        command2();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        command2failed(e);
    }
}
```

Whether or not this is important to you, I don't know, but I think it's important you know that just because `command2` is in a separate try/catch block, that still doesn't guarantee it will run, depending on how your error handling (failed to write file permission for example?)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have each command execute in it's own try/catch.
Once the exception is thrown, you go to the catch and can't get back to normal execution after the first command.

```
try{
    command1
}catch(Exception e){}

try{
    command2
}catch(Exception e){}

try{
    command3
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only do that by wrapping individual commands inside try-catch blocks themselves.

```
try {
   command1;
}
catch(Exception e) {
 // log this
}
try {
  command2;
}catch(Exception e){
 // log that
}
```

Thats pretty ugly though , so you might want to consider a redesign of sorts like try and encapsulate the individual commands inside methods that catch and log exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

if every command is a method it self you can just throw expceptions and catch them all with different error messages.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    //overide constructor to set your error message
}
```

... when implementing commands

```
public void command() throws MyException {
    try { //do some stuff
    } catch(Exception e) {
      throw new MyException("my message");
    }
}
```

... handle all exceptions of your commands

```
try {
   command1();
   command2();
} catch (MyException e) {
   // e.getMessage() will return your error message you used in the throws declaration...
}
```

You can also use a Command interface to make it easy to add more commands if needed.

Comment: This won't move on to command2 as per the question. This just translates an exception.